# pyChef: How do I disable SSL verification using chef.autoconfigure()

Tags: chef-infra, pychef

I'd like to start using pyChef but my dev environment has a self-signed certificate, so I keep getting an SSL error due to 'SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED'.

I see that chef.ChefAPI allows for ssl_verify=False, but does not work when using within chef.autoconfigure(). Can I auto-configure ssl verification?

I would like to make this script require no manual configuration from the user, how do I disable SSL verification using chef.autoconfigure(), or do I need to still need to call chef.ChefAPI on each query (or set default) and disable it there?

Maybe there are potential workarounds in Python as well to call the cert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't make that easy since I think disabling TLS should be an absolute last resort. If you're using a self-signed cert, you can do the normal thing of setting the `$SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable to the certificate path. But if you must:

```
api = chef.autoconfigure()
api.ssl_verify = False
```

Comment: Where do I set the $SSL_CERT_FILE to the certificate path? I've exported as a Linux env var, and tried to call it; I've tried calling it direct from defining a local python var, SSL_CERT_FILE='/path/to/cert', but am still getting SSL cert verify failures. Do I need to define this somewhere within pychef specifically? I've confirmed that it's been set using: print(os.environ['SSL_CERT_FILE'])

Comment: You just have to set it before start Python, otherwise normal rules apply. That's a feature of OpenSSL, not PyChef. Remember that that only helps if the cert has the correct SAN, i.e. if it's a trust root failure. If the cert itself is bad, no amount of trust DB manipulation will help.